# HttpContext User Identity Name is Lost C#

Tags: c#, authorization, httpcontext

I have a controller for Reporting and an `ActionResult` called `Issue` that issues the report to a customer.

One of the requirements is to generate a PDF (using nrecosite) which is called in the `Issue` ActionResult.

I'm using the nrecosite function `GeneratePdfFromFile` and passing in a URL that points to another `ActionResult` called `CreatePDF` in the same controller that returns a partial view which is in turn used to generate the PDF.

This all works great when I don't check that the current user is authorized. When I hit the `Issue` `ActionResult` the application checks for the current username and authorizes them fine.

But when the `CreatePDF` `ActionResult` is called the `HttpContext.User.Identity.Username` is blank which makes the application think the user is not authorized.

The code is not complete as I'm just trying to get this authorized part to work.

```
public JsonResult Issue(int id)
{
    string outputPath = "C:\\"test" + ".pdf";
    HtmlToPdfConverter pdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter()
    {
        Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
    };

    pdfConverter.GeneratePdfFromFile("http://test.debug/Statistics/CreatePDF/" + id, null, outputPath );

    return null;
}


public ActionResult CreatePDF(int id)
{
    Models.Statistics.Detail model = new Model.Statistics.Detail,(_reportingService);
    model.GetDetail(id);
    return PartialView("/Views/Statistics/Partials/_TestResultsPDF.cshtml", model);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, I think it didnt exist because the call was being made by the system. I just gave each user account a guid key and passed that when it was called. If an invalid guid was passed then it wouldnt download the PDF

Comment: Ok, where are you passing in the guid?